# How to use library in python or js?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, encryption

I'm python\js developer. I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt data with "GOST 28147-89 algorithm", but i can't understand how to USE it.

**data to encrypt**: `%some large text, like lorem1000%`

**key for encrypt**: 
 `afdfGRerehrehtwICJAAGByqFAwICHgEDQwAEQHuYflp31mEqb1YLSTOlzWJCUWDsDmNVZ9Lor7bkJfbrSnsFg7gcHGNuGoIhfds+Shgfhrtgergerfewwer7W2Wd3P+sPnrmtw=`

[PYTHON]

I did visited this site. There is an example for pygost.gost3410
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygost/3.5

But how to use pygost.gost28147???

My current status:

`from pygost.gost28147 import DEFAULT_SBOX
from pygost.gost28147 import BLOCKSIZE`

[JS]

There is also this guy http://gostcrypto.com/doc/GostCipher.html

My current status:

`let gost1 = new GostCipher('GOST 28147', 1989 , 64, 'ES')`

it outputs 
`Uncaught Error: Invalid block length`
because I need sBox in `new GostCipher` constructor, but where to find it?.

==============

Help!